# NextJS API axio setup

Tags: typescript, next.js, axios, proxy, next-api

Setup:
I have a NextJS application that fetches data from several external APIs and I want its own Next API to act as a gateway to determine which request goes where (that way I can neatly encapsulate the different API configurations and not worry about it). The App sends the request to the `/api` and that proxies it to the relevant external service.

I'm using `axios` through `react-query` to make those requests and on the client side it seems to work just fine but the monent I try to prefetch data on the backend it falls flat. Turns out I need to set the baseURL on the axios instance to the full url, not just the `/api` part (because the backend doesn't have a concept of basePath). But I have very little idea how to do that. Here's what I've tried so far.

```js
let apiURL = () => {
  if (process.browser) { return '/api' } // this is client side, no issues

  const host = process.env.VERCEL_URL || 'localhost';
  const port = process.env.NODE_PORT || '443';
  const protocol = process.env.NODE_PORT === '443' ? 'https' : 'http';
  return `${protocol}://${host}${port === '443' ? '' : `:${port}`}/api`;
}

export const http = axios.create({ baseURL: apiURL() })
```

Locally (both in the dev and production environments) it works great. Then I try deploying to Vercel and get a 500 error. It seems like the script is not picking up the env part or something or maybe it's completely unrelated since Vercel logs only give me a [partial error message](https://gist.github.com/almaron/f6a71b93f0713a97117ecb403231cc8b).

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Did you create the enviroments vars in your Vercel panel?

Comment: The VERCEL_URL is a system variable provided by default. NODE_PORT is set to 443.